# How to clean a dataframe column with hours and minutes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

[image]

I have a column of hours and minutes and I would like all values in the column to be in hours. So how do I divide only the columns values in minutes by 60 to get hours? I tried splitting the column by space to separate numbers and strings but I got stuck how to achieve the desire outcome.

Comment: make exampe text or code not image for answer

Comment: do you still want the unit to appear after the numeric value? Or have them all converted to hours and set to a numeric data type?

Comment: I don't want the units.  I want to convert all values to hours and set to a numeric data type thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) function to replace the units with their respective conversions. Then apply the pandas [eval](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html) function to each value to do the necessary conversions. Then [round](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html) to the desired number of decimal places.

```py
# Create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"content_duration": ['1.5 hours','1 hour','1.5 hours','1 hour', '37 mins','44 mins']})

# Convert the units to numeric datatype
df['content_duration'] = (df['content_duration'].replace({' mins?':'/60',' hours?':'*1'}, regex=True))\
                            .apply(pd.eval)\
                            .round(1)

# Print the dataframe
print(df)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
   content_duration
0               1.5
1               1.0
2               1.5
3               1.0
4               0.6
5               0.7
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a lambda with split.

```
df["content_duration"] = df["content_duration"].apply(
    lambda x: round(int(x.split(" ")[0]) / 60, 2) if x.split(" ")[1] == "mins" else x.split(" ")[0]
)

print(df)

  content_duration
0              1.5
1                1
2              1.5
3                1
4             0.62
5             0.73
```

Comment: I get "IndexError: list index out of range" running this code.

Comment: Perhaps your real data has NaN values?

Answer (score 0):

Pandas's [`to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) is very good at converting this, you just need to remove the `s` from `hours`/`mins`:

```
df['hours'] = (pd.to_timedelta(df['content_duration']
                               .str.replace(r's\b', '', regex=True))
                .dt.total_seconds().div(3600)
                .round(2) # optional
              )
```

Output:

```
  content_duration  hours
0        1.5 hours   1.50
1           1 hour   1.00
2        1.5 hours   1.50
3           1 hour   1.00
4          37 mins   0.62
5          44 mins   0.73
```

To have strings:

```
df['hours'] = (pd.to_timedelta(df['content_duration'].str.replace(r's\b', '', regex=True))
                .dt.total_seconds().div(3600).round(2)
                .astype(str).add(' hours')
              )
```

output:

```
  content_duration       hours
0        1.5 hours   1.5 hours
1           1 hour   1.0 hours
2        1.5 hours   1.5 hours
3           1 hour   1.0 hours
4          37 mins  0.62 hours
5          44 mins  0.73 hours
```